# How to wait for some time between user inputs in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am making a GUI program where the user can draw on a canvas in Tkinter. What I want to do is that I want the user to be able to draw on the canvas and when the user releases the `Mouse-1`, the program should wait for 1 second and clear the canvas. If the user starts drawing within that 1 second, the canvas should stay as it is.

I am able to get the user input fine. The draw function in my program is bound to `B1-Motion`.

I have tried things like inducing a time delay but I don't know how to check whether the user has started to draw again.

How do I check whether the user has started to draw again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `bind` the mouse click event to a function that sets a bool to True or False, then using `after` to call a function after 1 second which depending on that bool clears the screen.

Comment: I will try this and get back to you later. I think this might just work.

Comment: I implemented this and it is working but there is still an issue. I have bound my canvas to two methods- one with motion named draw() and other with mouse release named motion_end(). There is also a flag variable that is False by default. When the mouse motion starts, the flag is set to True in the draw() function. When the motion_end() is triggered, it sets the flag to False and calls the clear_canvas() method after 1 second. Now, in the clear_canvas() method, I am only clearing the canvas when the flag is False. More in next comment. I ran out of allowed characters

Comment: Now, when I tested the program, it is working for the initial inputs, but now, it is clearing within the input now. Can this be due to multiple after() events being triggered when there are a lot of mouse presses and releases?

Comment: @Prashant Goyal that's possible, you need to post the code to say anything